# R - formattable - trying to hide column 0

Tags: r, hide, formattable

I am displaying a dataframe using formattable

```
formattable (cohens_d_effects, digits = 2)
```

My table looks like this:

[image]

I am able to hide columns using the list argument when I got a column name:

```
formattable (cohens_d_effects, list (d_names = FALSE), digits = 2)
```

But how to hide these "id-numbers" on the left (column 0)?

---

Reproducible example from comment below:

```
d_names = 1:10 
d = 11:20 
Winners = 15:24 
a <- data.frame(d_names, d, Winners) 
a <- a[order(-d), ] 
b <- subset(a, d > 14) 
formattable(b, digits = 2)
```

Comment: Those are `row.names`, and are always there if your dataset is of class `"data.frame"`.

Comment: When I use `formattable` to display a data frame it doesn't include row names (e.g., `formattable(data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 21:30), digits = 2)`). Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @Lyngbakr  `d_names = 1:10`  `d = 11:20`  `Winners = 15:24`  `a <- data.frame(d_names, d, Winners)`  `a <- a[order (-d)]`  `b <- subset(a, d > 14)`  `formattable(b, digits = 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rui Barradas commented, those are row names. A simple solution is to set them to `NULL`,

```
# Load library
library(formattable)

# Example from above
d_names = 1:10 
d = 11:20 
Winners = 15:24 
a <- data.frame(d_names, d, Winners) 
a <- a[order(-d),] 
b <- subset(a, d > 14) 

# Set to NULL before creating the table
row.names(b) <- NULL

# Create the table
formattable(b, digits = 2)
```

giving,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as the thread-starter. Some dataframes gave me these "id-numbers" on the left (column 0) and other data.frames did not. Eventually I found out that if I had used the subset function either in the creation of the dataframe or as part as the formattable function as in the example below these id-numbers showed up.

So the solution for me to remove them was to generate the dataframe with filter function in package dplyr rather than subset from R base.

See this example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)

y <- sample(10)
x <- sample(10)
z <- data.frame(x,y)

formattable(subset(z, x==1))

formattable(filter(z, x==1))
```